# Save history on default Calculator on MS7

Tags: windows-7, calculator

Is it possible to save the history in the Calculator program in MS7 such that when you exit and restart it, the history is still there?

Comment: What is MS7....

Comment: he means MS Windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No the default calculator doesnt have that capability.  However, the Microsoft Mathematics 4.0 [calculator](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15702) can - and its free.

> Microsoft Mathematics provides a graphing calculator that plots in 2D and 3D, step-by-step equation solving, and useful tools to help students with math and science studies.